# Cold crashing bottled ale after fermentation

Tags: bottling, cold-crash

There are a few topics about this here but nothing that gives info on my particular situation...

I've fermented in primary for 1 1/2 weeks then transferred to secondary. Left the ale in there for another week and have just bottled my ale 2 days ago. The mix was still producing a heavy amount of gas at the time of bottling. The bottles are now in a dark environment at 20 degrees C.

Don't ask why i did it this way. I think i messed up a few things but we'll see on the final result.

When i bottled i added 1/2 teaspoon of priming sugar to each bottle and gently tipped the bottle till the sugar was dissolved. Iv'e got 35 pint bottles in total. They ale porcelain topped glass bottles.

My question is when should i cold crash the cloudy ale? Should i cold crash them in another day or two or can i just leave them bottled and cold crash when i was to drink in 2-6 weeks?

Also the ale was very bitter when i bottled it, could that be a sign of trouble? Or be just because it's still young?

Cheers, Brad

**EDIT: I think this is quite good info actually:**

[Am I required to refrigerate bottles after bottling?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/am-i-required-to-refrigerate-bottles-after-bottling?rq=1)

Didn't see it before...

So i should leave the cloudy ale in the bottle for a few weeks then cold crash when i want to drink?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have it.  Normally you cold crash at the end of fermentation, before bottling.  And a word of warning...if it was still outgassing heavily when you bottled it, it's likely fermentation wasn't finished.  Bottles could explode.  Keep it in a box in a closet, or somewhere safe.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So i should just cold crash before i drink in the next 2-12 weeks yeah? There's no harm in that. Or should i cold crash all at once? 

Aye i would cold crash the fermentor but have no way of refrigerating it. 

Also any idea about the bitter taste? Should that go away?

Comment: The bitter taste could be yeast still in suspension.  If you want the beer to carbonate, you need to keep it at room temp for a couple weeks.  I'd let it carb in a safe place (just in case) them put bottles in the fridge a few days before you intend to drink them.